# Positioning <img> nicely with rest of text in <h1>

Tags: css

I would like to position an `<img>` tag nicely with the rest of my text in a `<h1>` tag.

I have no idea how to do this though. Padding moves both text and image.

http://jsfiddle.net/vUCr9/ This is what I have, I would like the text to be nicely centered with the image.

Anyone got any good solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the `vertical-align`-ment of the image:

```
h1 {
    font:35px 'Russo One', sans-serif;
}
​h1 img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vUCr9/1/).

References:

- [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/vertical-align).

Comment: It won't work well for each image, positioning each image can get better result in most cases.

Comment: @methyl, I typically recommend avoiding positioning wherever possible.

Comment: @methyl: it meets the needs for two images: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vUCr9/6/)...

Comment: Key words, wherever possible. In this example the result isn't perfect.

Comment: @methyl, I feel that it's better to get close before using positioning to tweak it into perfection. I'm not saying that it's not useful or that it shouldn't be used; I'm simply advocating avoidance until it's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:relative` on `img` and then position it by `left: Xpx; top:Xpx` or whatever, like that:

```
img{
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  left: 4px;
}
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kstsV/7/)

Comment: Please include the original code in your question. If jsFiddle goes down your answer means nothing. Also, don't use inline styling, use an external stylesheet/style block.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
h1 img{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vUCr9/2/)**.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>HTML<img style="vertical-align:middle;" 
src="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1730750300/HTML5_Badge_128_normal.png" 
alt="5" /> LOGO</h1>
```

This is how you can fix it with inline style

[jsfiddle.net/JZGAF](http://jsfiddle.net/JZGAF/)